# How to reconcile interest in two (somewhat related) disciplines

Tags: career-path

I have two separate in-depth interests in two academic fields.  One of them in pure math (PhD in probability, also interested in complex analysis and differential geometry).  The other one is in software/computer science systems (privacy, distributed systems, this is where my current day-job is).
I do not want to spend my life having to give up one of them because I find both very interesting.  But apparently Morera once said that having very in-depth knowledge about a narrow field is better than superficial knowledge in several fields.  Is his advice correct?  Is it possible to make contributions in both areas?  I am currently 34 and in between early-career mid-career stage.

Thanks,